# Struts 2 and business objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts, business-objects

In a Struts 2 class where [http get params are auto fetched by field variables](http://pastie.org/8487719).    While there were repeated such class fields like `userId,groupId,` etc in many classes, I decided to make one **business object class `RequestParams`** in each class and put all the field there.

Then all my class will have just the `RequestParams rp;` with `getRp();` and `setRp();` the rp class will have the `userId` with getters / setters and all other fields.

Now I see I have to replace. e.g `userId` with `getRp()`.`getUserId();`  at line 34  Now the code is looking ugly.

With this: `messageId = ChatDao.saveMessage(userId,groupId , message);`

would look like

```
rp.setMessageId(  ChatDao.saveMessage(rp.getUserId(), rp.getGroupId(), rp.getMessag()   )   );
```

what is a better way of doing such things?

```
public class SendMessageOrStartChatAction extends BaseActoinSupport{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int userId;
    private int groupType;
    private int groupId;
    private String groupTitle;
    private String groupMemberIds;
    private int randomCode;
    private String message;
    private int messageId; //internal class ues


    @Override
    /** boo */
    protected void doExecute() throws IOException {



        //check if it had random code in db, (msg already saved in db)
        if(ChatDao.randomCodeExists(randomCode)){
            messageId = ChatDao.getMessageIdThatMatchesRandomCode(randomCode);  
            write(messageId);

        }else{
            if(groupId <= 0){
            //create group 
                groupId = ChatDao.createChatGroup(userId, groupTitle, groupType);
                String[] memberIdsArray = groupMemberIds.split("=="); 
                ChatDao.addUsersToGroup(groupId, memberIdsArray);
            }
            //save message
            messageId = ChatDao.saveMessage(userId,groupId , message);
            // queued: may be put this in last viewed messages here. may be.
            write(messageId);       
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this approach, if you aggregate a class and want to access its properties then public accessors are appropriate to you and you could also access them via OGNL. The action is on top of the `valueStack`, so expression will look much simpler `"rp.userId"` for example. Anyway there's no need to pass all params to the method, you can use a simplified method signature

```
ChatDao.saveMessage(rp);
```

and inside the method access those parameters.

Comment: while doing `rp.randomCode` I get "randomCode" has private access error

Comment: and how would just `ChatDao.saveMessage(rp);` would know what args and in what order does the `saveMessage` takes

Comment: Inside the method you could access them in any order.

Comment: while doing rp.randomCode I get "randomCode" has private access error. Do I have to make it public? thats not a good practice